# How to implement Gmail sso -- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gmail

I am new to this topic. i want to login my applications in various social networks(facebook, twitter & google). It will possible by doing single sign on(SSO). I implemented twitter and facebook, but i bit confused on integrating Gmail sso. I searched several ways, but cant find exact documentation. First of all, is that possible to do, can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read and send GMail, check out GMail API on OAuth2

https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i dont want to read or send from gmail. Simply i want to login my app using gamail, once done it should re-direct to my app.

Comment: So you want a person to login to your app using their Google account?
i.e. "Sign in with Google"
Then you can look at Google+ Platform at https://developers.google.com/+/

Comment: ya, i want the same what you saying now.